# Using an index to create a PHP PDO Query?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am currently working on a project that is to create a survey website. My idea is that each time a user clicks next, a new question will appear. Each question in the mysql database has a question order named 'q_order'(not sure if this is the best approach). I am trying to call a jquery function on that click that increases an index by 1 then sends it to a PHP file which then creates a query with that index number for the question. I am using this in my JS function:

```
function sample2() {
    pindex = pindex + 1;
    $('#question').load('DBSurvey.php?index' + pindex);
}
```

In my PHP I have this:

```
<?php
    $user='***';
    $pass='***';
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=***', $user, $pass);
        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } 
    catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
    $index = 0;
    $index = $_GET['index'];    

    $sth = $dbh->prepare('SELECT question FROM Questions where q_order=:index');
    $sth->execute(array(":index" => $index));
    $question = $sth->fetchAll();
    $numRecords = sth->rowCount();
    if($numRecords < 1)
        echo "no records";
    else
        print_r($question);
?>
```

My problem is that nothing at all gets echoed and I am not sure why. Sometimes I was able to get "Array( )" printed which I think means it is an empty array? I am not not sure why it would be empty because when I do this same prepare statement in my mysql console, I get the correct result. I am looking to see what I can do next to trouble shoot? Any advice on how to set this up better? Am I even on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `$('#question').load('DBSurvey.php?index' + pindex);` should be `$('#question').load('DBSurvey.php?index=' + pindex);`

Comment: rowCount() might not return the number of rows for SELECT.Use a query with COUNT.Yeah,PDO is not perfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function sample2() {
    pindex = pindex + 1;
    $('#question').load('DBSurvey.php?index' + pindex);
}
```

Is wrong. A GET parameter should have the following form : ?variable=value. You simply forgot to add the "=" sign.

One thing that I can't help to notice is when you use pindex = pindex + 1;. You should use pindex++ to make your code cleaner.

In the end your function should be :

```
function sample2() {
    pindex++;
    $('#question').load('DBSurvey.php?index=' + pindex);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I originally had pindex++; but changed it, I don't know why. I will look into what you said.

Comment: Glad to hear it help you out. If it did solve the problem, don't forget to click on the checkmark to accept the answer. Welcome to StackOverflow!